# Relative propagation delay matching instead of length matching in PCB design?

Tags: pcb-design

Why do we need to use relative propagation delay matching instead of length matching in PCB design?

Answer (score 3):

The receiving end doesn't care about the distance a signal traveled, it cares about whether it arrives in proper timing.

Hence, you need to "repair" the relative delay, not the length. A length difference is *one* reason why delays might not be the same; others include intended and parasitic components, substrate differences, on-chip skews ...

Comment: thanks for your input, and still I'm not clear. Ex,1000 MIL trace has X delay. so if i match the group of signal with 1000 MIL,then they should've reach at same time. am i correct?

Comment: Have you read the last sentence in my answer?

Comment: @Krish No, as Marcus Müller stated there are more effects except length which will affect the signals e.g. vias, what is placed near/under the traces,... also your traces might be perfectly matched for a narrow frequency band, but not for other frequencies. It's an advanced topic. Note: The current of the signal travels through the trace. the electromagnetic field of the signal travels through the dielectric materials which surround the conductor

Comment: I red again, now i understand and clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the previous answers, length matching in PCB is performed so that signals meet timing constraints. So the important thing is time not length. Length is just a way of dealing with this problem but is not a “safe” approach if other conditions are overlooked.

If for example we have two time sensitive signals on top layer traveling along all the way from one point to another and we length match them then we are probably ok because they run under same conditions and their arrival time would be the same. But if we run one of the two on top and the other on a different layer then their arrival times would be different because different layers have different propagation times so we have to compensate for that mismatch by using different lengths.